# Removing pixels of one color from a bitmapdata

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a map (map of a mall, top view) with some colors.
I´m removing the part for walking of the map, which has a type of color (say 0xcccccc).

I got all the 0xcccccc color pixels removed (setted to another color), but it seems to remain a bit of gray at the walking part.

The color of that bit it´s close to 0xcccccc. It looks like flash not succeeded while removing the walking part. But instead, leaved some parts (like borders or something) on the bitmapdata.

I´ve tried to remove by script, by picking the colors remained on the bitmap, but the loop doesn´t find these colors.

What could I do?

Thanks

Comment: Do you use jpg images? Also, can you post the code you use to remove the 0xcccccc color pixels?

Comment: I´ve pick a movieclip which has a png inside. I´ve drawn the walk part (0xcccccc color) with flash, so the walk part is a vector. Then I created a bitmap for this movieclip, then, I´ve tried to remove the 0xcccccc color from the bitmapdata. And I got that strange kind of thing.

Comment: post more information. your code. bitmapdata creation flags. your image.

Comment: From how you describe it it sounds like during the rasterization of the vector into the bitmapdata it's probably doing some sort of anti-aliasing where it ends up blending the background color with your vector path color, for those regions you won't have an exact match anymore.  Try using a solid colored background png then look for pixels that are not the background color rather than looking for your path color to see if it is in fact a slight offset from your path color that's the result of blending.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose you two different answers :)

**1. Layers and Blending modes:**

It is possible to put the content in to separate layers?

If is it possible you may try to use blending modes to do that, in the first one you have the image you want to show and in the second one you have another one that would act as a mask.

Then you could use BlendMode.LAYER (first layer) + BlendMode.ERASE ( mask layer ) which is called inversive mask.

**2. Pixel Bender**

Using pixel bender you could create a filter with some parameters which would do super fast calculations on your images.

One of this calculations could be set the alpha to 0 to all colors matching certain R,G,B.

Hope it helps!